# Synapse workspace deployment override defaultValue of trigger schedule

Tags: yaml, azure-synapse, cicd

A trigger on our Synapse workspace needs different trigger times on different environments. During deployment the times are overriden by the default value that's part of the TemplateForWorkspace.sjon file in the workspace_publish branch.

```
    },
        "Load from FTP_properties_typeProperties_recurrence_schedule": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "minutes": [
                    0
                ],
                "hours": [
                    3
                ]
            }
        },
```

To override parameters during deployment, we use the OverrideArmParameters option of the Synapse workspace deployment@2 taks.

```
- task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
            displayName: Synapse workspace deployment
            inputs:
              operation: 'deploy'
              TemplateFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/synapse_template/TemplateForWorkspace.json
              ParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/synapse_template/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
              ResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.deploymentResourceGroupName }}
              TargetWorkspaceName: '$(DeployWorkspaceName)'
              DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: true
              DeployManagedPrivateEndpoints: false
              OverrideArmParameters: |
                KeyVault_properties_typeProperties_baseUrl: xxxx${{ parameters.environment }}xxx
                Datalake_properties_typeProperties_url: xxxx${{ parameters.environment }}xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net
```

How to override the hours of the trigger? I've tried some things like:

```
Load from FTP_properties_typeProperties_recurrence_schedule: 0,9
```

This results in empty time boxes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

some parameters are not overridable by default. You need to specify the parameters that you want to override in `template-parameters-definition.json' that you put into the root of you synapse workspace. The file is is described e.g. in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#create-custom-parameters-in-the-workspace-template.

In your case, you will want to specify there something like

```json
 "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/triggers": {
        "properties": {
            "typeProperties": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "*": "=",
                    "interval": "=:triggerSuffix:int",
                    "frequency": "=:-freq"
                },
                "maxConcurrency": "="
            }
        }
    },
```

This json is based on the json representation of the triggers, so any other parameter that you want to include, you can.

Then, when you publish your changes, the `TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json` will include the newly overridable parameters for you triggers. Then you only need to take their names and override them in the `Synapse workspace deployment` task.